# Does qt creator (4.13.2) support MTd under debug mode

Tags: qt

My project is set to be Mtd like as follow:

> QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG =-Zi -MTd
>
> QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG = -Zi -MTd

And I tried to convert QString to const character* like this:

```
QString ss = "sdfdsfdsf";
const char* sst = ss.toStdString().c_str();
```

Then app crashes, it show the debug assertion failed

> (_acrt_first_block == header)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sst` points to destroyed memory, because you call c_str() on a temporary object which is destroyed right after this line of code finishes its execution.

So it's not a problem of `Qt Creator`, it's a bug of your code.

Comment: But if I use -MDd, then it's ok